# What is the most efficient way for a mobile app to utilize an API being served on Google App Engine?

Tags: django, rest, api, google-app-engine, mobile

I am in the research stage of building my first app.

I am a complete noob and the amount of information for all the different approaches in building an app is relatively overwhelming.

My situation is that I currently have a web project being served by Google App Engine. This web project connects customers to a subscription-based portal. I used Django and its RESTful API as the backend.

Now I've decided I want to create a hybrid app that utilizes the current REST API I have set up for the web project since the app will be accessing the same databases and authentication methods.

However, I'm not sure what the best approach is in taking on this task.

So far I've read a lot about Firebase and all its features, but it seems to offer more than what I currently need.

I also read about Google Cloud Endpoints.

The one that seems to be the most desirable is connecting directly to my Rest API, but I am getting the impression that this is only doable in Google Compute Engine.

So for anyone out there who has experience with these various interfaces, what are the pros and cons of each of these to connect to a backend API and which option is the most feasible given my experience and current setup?

Thanks!

Comment: maybe this link will help you https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-app-backend-services#design-pattern